# Create dataframe from a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

How to get a data frame with the same data as an already existing matrix has?

A simplified example of my matrix:

```
mat <- matrix(c(0, 0.5, 1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5),
              ncol = 3, nrow = 3,
              dimnames = list(NULL, c("time", "C_0", "C_1")))

> mat
     time C_0 C_1
[1,]  0.0 0.1 0.3
[2,]  0.5 0.2 0.4
[3,]  1.0 0.3 0.5
```

I would like to create a data frame that looks like this:

```
     name   time   val
1    C_0    0.0    0.1
2    C_0    0.5    0.2
3    C_0    1.0    0.3
4    C_1    0.0    0.3
5    C_1    0.5    0.4
6    C_1    1.0    0.5
```

All my attempts are quite clumsy, for example:

```
data.frame(cbind(c(rep("C_1", 3), rep("C_2", 3)),
                 rbind(cbind(mat[,"time"], mat[,"C_0"]),
                       cbind(mat[,"time"], mat[,"C_1"]))))
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this more elegantly? Please note that my real data has a few more columns (40 columns).

Comment: You are looking for `?melt`.   Also search for `[r] reshape2` in the SO search box

Comment: More info here: [www.statmethods.net/management/reshape.html](http://www.statmethods.net/management/reshape.html).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you change your `time` column into row names, then you can use `as.data.frame(as.table(mat))` for simple cases like this.

Example:

```
data <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5)
dimnames <- list(time=c(0, 0.5, 1), name=c("C_0", "C_1"))
mat <- matrix(data, ncol=2, nrow=3, dimnames=dimnames)
as.data.frame(as.table(mat))
  time name Freq
1    0  C_0  0.1
2  0.5  C_0  0.2
3    1  C_0  0.3
4    0  C_1  0.3
5  0.5  C_1  0.4
6    1  C_1  0.5
```

In this case time and name are both factors. You may want to convert time back to numeric, or it may not matter.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `stack` from the base package. But, you need first to coerce your matrix to a `data.frame` and to reorder the columns once the data is stacked.

```
mat <- as.data.frame(mat)
res <- data.frame(time= mat$time,stack(mat,select=-time))
res[,c(3,1,2)]

  ind time values
1 C_0  0.0    0.1
2 C_0  0.5    0.2
3 C_0  1.0    0.3
4 C_1  0.0    0.3
5 C_1  0.5    0.4
6 C_1  1.0    0.5
```

Note that `stack` is generally more efficient than the `reshape2` package.

Comment: I prefer the `stack` solution, also because I won't need to load `reshape2`

Comment: (Technically, `stack` is in the `utils` package, loaded by default in interactive R sessions.)

Answer (score 6):

`melt()` from the **reshape2** package gets you close ...

```
library(reshape2)
(res <- melt(as.data.frame(mat), id="time"))
#   time variable value
# 1  0.0      C_0   0.1
# 2  0.5      C_0   0.2
# 3  1.0      C_0   0.3
# 4  0.0      C_1   0.3
# 5  0.5      C_1   0.4
# 6  1.0      C_1   0.5
```

... although you may want to post-process its results to get your preferred column names and ordering.

```
setNames(res[c("variable", "time", "value")], c("name", "time", "val"))
#   name time val
# 1  C_0  0.0 0.1
# 2  C_0  0.5 0.2
# 3  C_0  1.0 0.3
# 4  C_1  0.0 0.3
# 5  C_1  0.5 0.4
# 6  C_1  1.0 0.5
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried  `melt(mat, id="time")` after the comments above but couldn't figure out that I need `as.data.frame(mat)`

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- as_data_frame(mat) %>%      # convert the matrix to a data frame
  gather(name, val, C_0:C_1) %>%  # convert the data frame from wide to long
  select(name, time, val)         # reorder the columns

df
# A tibble: 6 x 3
   name  time   val
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1   C_0   0.0   0.1
2   C_0   0.5   0.2
3   C_0   1.0   0.3
4   C_1   0.0   0.3
5   C_1   0.5   0.4
6   C_1   1.0   0.5
```

Comment: Any tips for how to do this on one of the triangles of a matrix?  I have a mirrored matrix so I end up with duplicate values.  using upper.tri strips out the names.

Comment: Hmm - not sure off the top of my head. That might be better broken off as its own separate question with some example data.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following "cheat" to work very neatly and error-free

```
dimnames <- list(time=c(0, 0.5, 1), name=c("C_0", "C_1"))
mat <- matrix(data, ncol=2, nrow=3, dimnames=dimnames)
head(mat, 2) #this returns the number of rows indicated in a data frame format
df <- data.frame(head(mat, 2)) #"data.frame" might not be necessary
```

Et voila!

Answer (score 0):

A Renewed Approach using `pivot_longer` from the `tidyr` package and `dplyr` syntax.
For get the same output

```
> mat <- matrix(c(0, 0.5, 1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5),
+               ncol = 3, nrow = 3,
+               dimnames = list(NULL, c("time", "C_0", "C_1")))
> mat
     time C_0 C_1
[1,]  0.0 0.1 0.3
[2,]  0.5 0.2 0.4
[3,]  1.0 0.3 0.5

mat %>% as_tibble() %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=-time) %>%
  select(name,time,value) %>% 
  arrange(name)  

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  name   time value
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 C_0     0     0.1
2 C_0     0.5   0.2
3 C_0     1     0.3
4 C_1     0     0.3
5 C_1     0.5   0.4
6 C_1     1     0.5
```