# Convert columns to rows keeping the name of the column

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there any way in R to Convert columns to rows keeping the name of the column?

Example input:

```
A   B
1   1
2   3
3   4
44  5
```

Output

```
 Group Number
  A       1
  A       2
  A       3
  A       44 
  B       1
  B       3
  B       4
  B       5
```

Comment: What search terms have you tried before asking here?

Comment: Buzz words for searching are "melt", "cast", "reshape", "wide" and "long".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use `reshape2`.

```
> x <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 55:51)
> library(reshape2)
> melt(x)
Using  as id variables
   variable value
1         A     1
2         A     2
3         A     3
4         A     4
5         A     5
6         B    55
7         B    54
8         B    53
9         B    52
10        B    51
```

It was interesting to see the benchmarks. `melt` prints a message by default that we can turn off by being more explicit when calling a function.

```
> microbenchmark(stack(DF), melt(DF), times=100)
    Unit: milliseconds
          expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
     stack(DF) 122.3086 133.8435 139.6990 180.5338 250.9316   100
      melt(DF) 140.0183 198.2025 227.8125 245.3444 367.1552   100
```

I find the difference small, and it gets smaller when printing for `melt` is turned off. Looks like that my hunch of turning verbose mode off in my simulations may have helped.

```
> microbenchmark(stack(DF), melt(DF, measure.vars = names(DF)[grepl("X", names(DF))]), times=100)
Unit: milliseconds
                                                      expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
                                                 stack(DF) 94.33681 124.9958 132.1747 144.7323 287.7438   100
 melt(DF, measure.vars = names(DF)[grepl("X", names(DF))]) 99.44282 141.0594 150.2625 178.8081 249.0888   100
```

Answer (score 11):

No need to use `reshape2`, you can use the `stack` function from base-R :

With `your.data` as your example:

```
res <- stack(your.data)
colnames(res) = c("Number", "Group")
```

gives you

```
> res
  Number Group
1      1     A
2      2     A
3      3     A
4     44     A
5      1     B
6      3     B
7      4     B
8      5     B
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885111/r-create-data-frame-from-matrix).

---

Benchmarking `melt` from `reshape2` and `stack` from base on bigger data:

```
require(reshape2)
set.seed(45)
DF <- data.frame(matrix(sample(20, 1e6, TRUE), ncol=100))

require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(stack(DF), melt(DF), times=100)

Unit: milliseconds
      expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 stack(DF) 157.7084 187.1993 241.8206 251.7132 334.5488   100
  melt(DF) 174.6079 253.1088 261.6234 273.3971 443.9953   100
```

Seems like `stack` is faster, but by a margin of 20 milliseconds...

Comment: @Thomas, it'd be also useful to edit the benchmarking in the post (preferably with larger data).

Comment: @Thomas, doesn't seem twice as fast... at least with this data size.

Comment: If you mean by doing "system.time", then yes, it's very likely to be inconsistent.

Comment: I just ran 5 times, on new session each... The median time differs, but the difference between the two are in the range of 20 and 40 ms.

Comment: @Arun Thanks for adding the benchmarking, I see about 50 ms difference.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Very interesting. Perhaps you should edit both of those tests (or the link to them) into this post. Then we can clean up these comments.