# Reshape matrix to data frame

Tags: r, matrix

I have association matrix file that looks like this (4 rows and 3 columns) .

```
test=read.table("test.csv", sep=",", header=T)
head(test)
            LosAngeles   SanDiego    Seattle    
            1            2           3          
A    1      0.1          0.2         0.2        
B    2      0.2          0.4         0.2        
C    3      0.3          0.5         0.3        
D    4      0.2          0.5         0.1
```

What I want to is reshape this matrix file into data frame. The result should look something like this (12(= 4 * 3) rows and 3 columns):

```
RowNum    ColumnNum    Value
1         1            0.1
2         1            0.2
3         1            0.3
4         1            0.2
1         2            0.2
2         2            0.4
3         2            0.5
4         2            0.5
1         3            0.2
2         3            0.2
3         3            0.3
4         3            0.1
```

That is, if my matrix file has 100 rows and 90 columns. I want to make new data frame file that contains 9000 (= 100 * 90) rows and 3 columns.

I've tried to use reshape package but but I do not seem to be able to get it right. Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Comment: try this `as.data.frame(as.table(test))` from (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885111/r-create-data-frame-from-matrix)

Comment: Can you provide `dput(head(test))` ?

Comment: Perhaps `melt` in the `reshape2` package could help (qualify this with i am a bit unsure of your data format - doesn't look like 4 rows / 3 columns)

Comment: Thank you, Osssan! Unfortunately, I also did read question before I post it but it did not work for me.

Comment: Thank you very much, David!!!Actually the data I have looks like this....dput(head(test))......structure(list(X.1 = c(NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), GO.0000165 = c(1, 
0.285, 0.336, 0.183, 0.067, 0.062), GO.0001505 = c(2, 0.215, 
0.197, 0.19, 0.084, 0.078), GO.0001568 = c(3, 0.11, 0.104, 0.13, 
0.091, 0.084), GO.0001944 = c(4, 0.086, 0.083, 0.105, 0.089, 
0.082), GO.0001975 = c(5, 0.043, 0.093, 0.05, 0.086, 0.079), 
    GO.0002755 = c(6, 0.176, 0.245, 0.116, 0.101, 0.096), .......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
test <- as.matrix(read.table(text="
            1            2           3          
    1      0.1          0.2         0.2        
    2      0.2          0.4         0.2        
    3      0.3          0.5         0.3        
    4      0.2          0.5         0.1", header=TRUE)) 

data.frame(which(test==test, arr.ind=TRUE), 
                 Value=test[which(test==test)], 
                 row.names=NULL)
#   row col Value
#1    1   1   0.1
#2    2   1   0.2
#3    3   1   0.3
#4    4   1   0.2
#5    1   2   0.2
#6    2   2   0.4
#7    3   2   0.5
#8    4   2   0.5
#9    1   3   0.2
#10   2   3   0.2
#11   3   3   0.3
#12   4   3   0.1
```

Comment: I was also going to answer with some a bit more terse: `library(reshape2);melt(test);`. Then I realized that your approach is over 3 times faster (on my computer). Odd, I wouldn't call this the most elegant way but definitely a faster one. Nice work.

Comment: maybe `data.frame(row = c(row(test)), col = c(col(test)), Value = c(test))`

Comment: @flodel When the matrix gets larger (e.g. 1000 x 1000), your suggestion is much faster (6x faster on my machine).  Cool!  On this small example, the one I posted is marginally (~ 8%) faster.

Answer (score 3):

Use `as.data.frame.table`. Its the boss:

```
m <- matrix(data = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.2,
                     0.2, 0.4, 0.2,
                     0.3, 0.5, 0.3, 
                     0.2, 0.5, 0.1),
            nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE, 
            dimnames = list(row = 1:4, col = 1:3))
m
#    col
# row   1   2   3
#   1 0.1 0.2 0.2
#   2 0.2 0.4 0.2
#   3 0.3 0.5 0.3
#   4 0.2 0.5 0.1

as.data.frame.table(m)
#    row col Freq
# 1    1   1  0.1
# 2    2   1  0.2
# 3    3   1  0.3
# 4    4   1  0.2
# 5    1   2  0.2
# 6    2   2  0.4
# 7    3   2  0.5
# 8    4   2  0.5
# 9    1   3  0.2
# 10   2   3  0.2
# 11   3   3  0.3
# 12   4   3  0.1
```